# Advantages of Chan's method over the Kalman filter

Tags: signal-analysis, signal-detection, localization

For a 3-receiver tracking system. Chan's positioning method gives an exact solution to the location problem. However in the literature, I saw that one could use the extended Kalman filter which is based on a distance with a receiver. Thanks to several consecutive transmissions the trajectory of the target can be found.

Here is my question: What are the benefits of using Chan's method instead of using the extended Kalmamn filter? Positioning looks better with the extended Kalman filter.

Comment: well, Chan's method works with *one* set of measurements. How many measurements do you need unitl your Kalman filter approach has sufficiently converged?

Comment: There is not enough information in your question to give you an answer.  There is no one Kalman filter -- a Kalman filter is a state estimator that is designed by a particular method, originated by Kalman.  If you mean how any algorithm that makes a single-measurement position estimate stacks up against a sensor-fusion scheme that uses an IMU and a TDOA navigation system (such as GPS) and a Kalman filter, then _edit your question_ to reflect that fact.